# Push off-canvas sidebar - How to smooth transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason the main area of the grid does not transit smoothly when I click on toggle button. There is a gap between the `sidebarTwo` and `main` area.
Let me know if I am doing something wrong when trying to implement push off-canvas sidebar using CSS Grid.

Here are

```
 grid-template-areas:
    'header header header'
    'main main sidebarTwo'
    'footer footer footer';
```

**code**

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('#category-tabs');
const toggleBtnOne = document.querySelector('#toggleOne');
const sidebarMainOne = document.querySelector('.main');
const sidebarMainTwo = document.querySelector('.sidebarTwo');

const replaFunction = () => {
  toggleBtnOne.classList.contains('fa-toggle-on') ?
    toggleBtnOne.classList.replace('fa-toggle-on', 'fa-toggle-off') :
    toggleBtnOne.classList.replace('fa-toggle-off', 'fa-toggle-on');

  sidebarMainOne.classList.toggle('active');
  sidebarMainTwo.classList.toggle('active');
};


toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', replaFunction);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,900|Six+Caps');
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 8fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'main main sidebarTwo' 'footer footer footer';
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.box {
  background: #ff4365;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #2c343b;
  color: #e9d20f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #ecedf2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.5em;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'charts' 'trading';
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.sidebarTwo {
  grid-area: sidebarTwo;
  width: 260px;
  right: -260px;
  background: #2c343b;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.sidebarTwo.active {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateX(260px);
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.charts {
  grid-area: charts;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.trading {
  grid-area: trading;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(200px, 600px);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-areas: 'one one two two two two';
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  height: auto;
  background: #495867;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #2c343b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header active">
      <div id="category-tabs">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="left"
          ><i id="toggleOne" class="fas fa-toggle-on fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
      </div>

      <h1 class="header-title">CSS Grid - grid-template-areas</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarTwo"></div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="trading">
        <div class="box one">1</div>
        <div class="box two">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="charts">
        <div class="box three">3</div>
        <div class="box four">4</div>
        <div class="box five">5</div>
        <div class="box six">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the div "main" you use a width auto and the transition need numbers to works.

Comment: you mean `max-width: auto;` ? I deleted it. no change.

Comment: Yes. transition need initial and finish number, i.e width 100% and width 800px or witdth: calc (100% - 250px). Something like this. Without numbers can't calculate the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Not the best solution but it works.

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('#category-tabs');
const toggleBtnOne = document.querySelector('#toggleOne');
const sidebarMainOne = document.querySelector('.main');

const sidebarMainTwo = document.querySelector('.sidebarTwo');

const replaFunction = () => {
  toggleBtnOne.classList.contains('fa-toggle-on')
    ? toggleBtnOne.classList.replace('fa-toggle-on', 'fa-toggle-off')
    : toggleBtnOne.classList.replace('fa-toggle-off', 'fa-toggle-on');

sidebarMainOne.classList.toggle('active'); sidebarMainTwo.classList.toggle('active');
};

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', replaFunction);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,900|Six+Caps');

* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 8fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header'
    'main main sidebarTwo'
    'footer footer footer';
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.box {
  background: #ff4365;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #2c343b;
  color: #e9d20f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #ecedf2;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.5em;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'charts' 'trading';
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.sidebarTwo {
  grid-area: sidebarTwo;
  position: fixed;
  right: -360px;
  width: 360px;
  background: #2c343b;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.sidebarTwo.active {
 transform: translateX(-360px);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.main.active {
  width: calc(100% - 410px);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.charts {
  grid-area: charts;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.trading {
  grid-area: trading;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(200px, 600px);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-areas: 'one one two two two two';
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  height: auto;
  background: #495867;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #2c343b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header active">
      <div id="category-tabs">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="left"
          ><i id="toggleOne" class="fas fa-toggle-on fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
      </div>

      <h1 class="header-title">CSS Grid - grid-template-areas</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarTwo"></div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="trading">
        <div class="box one">1</div>
        <div class="box two">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="charts">
        <div class="box three">3</div>
        <div class="box four">4</div>
        <div class="box five">5</div>
        <div class="box six">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```